# Flutter old app upgrading to use it today

Tags: flutter

I've found this code for flutter home automation application.
but it was wrote in an older version of flutter, which i tried many times to start it but i couldn't make it,
last best thing that i have ever came to was that i could could mergrated the application to Android X and the application was starting but when i try to sign up a new mail inside it it says,
Error fetching data.
It dosen't use Firebase to store email it just uses a SQL package.
if any one can help to git the code and upgrade it for me to use it i will be very thankful :D.
Here is the link,
https://github.com/mlinarevicMateo/home-automation-flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app is dependant on a webservice to run. Check lib/utils/network_util.dart. So you won't be able to get it run unless you write a new backend.

Answer (score 0):

As the project was created in an older version of flutter you might be missing some latest flutter modules you can add those to your existing project by running this command within your project directory.

`flutter create .`